# Flutter Toggle Airplane Mode

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to change Airplane Mode state with Flutter.

Like:

```dart
AirplaneMode.active();
AirplaneMode.disable()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airplane mode service flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852344/airplane-mode-service-flutter)